# ProgressDialog throws error in Android when passed an Application

Tags: android

I am getting the following exception :

```
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:566) ~[na:0.0]
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:272) ~[na:0.0]
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69) ~[na:0.0]
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298) ~[na:0.0]
            at kujo.app.ui.VerificationCallingDeviceActivity$2.showDialogIfNotShowing(VerificationCallingDeviceActivity.java:162) ~[na:0.0]
            at kujo.app.ui.VerificationCallingDeviceActivity$2.trySigningIn(VerificationCallingDeviceActivity.java:179) ~[na:0.0]
            at kujo.app.ui.VerificationCallingDeviceActivity$2.onReceiveCalled(VerificationCallingDeviceActivity.java:220) ~[na:0.0]
            at kujo.app.ui.IncomingCall.fireListeners(IncomingCall.java:54) ~[na:0.0]
            at kujo.app.ui.IncomingCall.onReceive(IncomingCall.java:79) ~[na:0.0]
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:861) ~[na:0.0]
```

This happens at line where ProgressDialog.show() function gets called.

I have created the ProgressDialog like:

```
new ProgressDialog(VoipApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
```

Where VoipApplication is a class which extends Application.

In some posts i read that ProgressDialog must be used for an Activity.
Otherwise this error will come. 
Is there any alternative that i can try so as to use ProgressDialog.

Comment: don not use `getApplicationContext()` for `ProgressDialog`. Rather, use `this` if your code is in your `Activity` class or use an object of your activity context.

Answer (score 0):

Use Notifications if you want to inform user about ongoing thing, like the play store does.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try

```
new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
```

or

```
new ProgressDialog("Class_name that extends Application".getInstance().getApplication());
```